# How can I get menu item in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-menu, android-design-library, android-navigationview

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    />
```

I am using `android.support.design.library` for material design.

What I want is to hide some menu items when the user is not logged-in.

Now I have trouble to get the menu item in `NavigationView`.

I have tried:

```
MenuItem logoutItem = (MenuItem) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.menu_logout);
logoutItem.setVisible(false);
```

But it's not working.

**How can I do this?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can get that by method of **[NavigationView.getMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getMenu())**

```
Menu menuNav = mNavigationView.getMenu();
```

Then you can find specific item by

```
MenuItem logoutItem = menuNav.findItem(R.id.menu_logout);
```

#### See [Official documentation for NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: I thought already the first line, and Now I get the second line from you!

Answer (score 9):

I think you should first get the menu like this:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(false);
```

The main aspect of this code is calling  navigationView.getMenu() to get the menu from this you will have a reference of current inflated menu and call findViewById() and after that you can whatever you what.

For Group of item ex:-

```
<group
android:id="@+id/group_1"
android:checkableBehavior="single"
android:visible="false">
...
```

and then you can control this using :-

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_1, true)
```

Answer (score 6):

just use below way

```
nav_draw = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_draw);
nav_draw.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_item_1).setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the item by

```
navigationView.Menu.GetItem(menu_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View navHeader=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

navMenu=navigationView.getMenu();

1. List item

   ```
   //work for login and logout menu
   if (MyPreferences.getBoolean(BaseActivity.this,ConstantValues.KEY_IS_LOGIN)){
       navMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
       navMenu.getItem(9).setVisible(true);
   }else {
       navMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
       navMenu.getItem(9).setVisible(false);
   }
   ```