# NullPointerException when trying to set title of item in drawer menu

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, menuitem, navigation-drawer

On an Android app with min SDK v. 16 and target SDK v. 23 I want to programmatically change the title of a menu item which belongs to the drawer menu. I thought it would be a simple matter of doing:

```
MenuItem myMenuItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_gallery);
myMenuItem.setTitle("New title"); // <---------- NullPointerException
```

but I'm obviously not accessing the object correctly:

**Logcat:**

```
02-22 19:10:16.707 5798-5798/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:86)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:298)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:443)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:60)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas? Here is the relevant code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />     <!-- I want to change the title of this item -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem myMenuItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_gallery);
    myMenuItem.setTitle("New title"); // <---------- NullPointerException

    return true;
}
...
```

Comment: Where do you add your `activity_main_drawer.xml` to the menu?

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265530/how-can-i-get-menu-item-in-navigationview?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery)` instead.

Comment: NavigationView nav_draw = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
nav_draw.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery).setTitle("New title");

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get menu item:

```
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuItem gallery = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_gallery);
       gallery.setTitle("New title");
    }
```

Comment: This throws the same NullPointerException.

Comment: use this code in
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {} method

Comment: Same issue. Note that it should be "public boolean".